# access harbor registry installed in minikube from the internet

Tags: harbor

- I install harbor using:
  helm install registry harbor/harbor --namespace devops --set expose.type="clusterIP" --set expose.tls.enabled="false" --set registry.relativeurls="true" --set expose.clusterIP.name="harbor" --set expose.clusterIP.ports.httpPort="8080" --set externalURL="http://harbor.devops.svc:8080" --set harborAdminPassword="admin" --set registry.credentials.username="admin" --set registry.credentials.password="admin"

I try to access harbor registry in the browser using this  url :http://harbor.devops.svc:8080
but it gave unable to connect